# How to fix "Root element is missing." when doing a Visual Studio (VS) Build?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-build-professional

How to fix "Root element is missing." when doing a Visual Studio (VS) Build?

Any idea what file I should look at in my solution?

Actually, I am getting this error message inside of "Visual Build Pro" when using using the "Make VS 2008" command. This command works just fine when building other solutions (like about 20) and I am not really sure why mine is getting the error.

Any help would be very much appreciated. :)

I am using VS 2008 and Visual Build Pro 6.7.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Make sure any XML file (or any file that would be interpreted as an XML file by visual studio) has a correct XML structure - that is, one root element (with any name, I have use `rootElement` in my example):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<rootElement>
 ...
</rootElement>
```

Comment: There are like thousands of files in my solution. Any special extensions to look at?

Comment: @Gerhard Weiss - .xml, .config, .xsd, .xsl would be a good start. If you have any XHTML files, they are also good candidates. I don't know anything about your project and what kind of files you have in it, so I can't really tell you. However, look at the error in the error window - it should tell you which file is causing the problem.

Comment: Worked briefly, but had to use Kahlil's answer.

Answer (score 94):

In my case it was the xxxxxxxxxxxx.vcxproj.user file that was causing the problem; it was blank after a crash. I renamed it and the problem went away.

Comment: Deleted my `.user` file and it worked again.. It was also blank after a SVN update

Comment: In my case I was running VS 2015 - Community Edition when my machine crashed. When I tried to open my solution the project wouldn't load and was throwing a "root element is missing" error. Deleting the .user file for the projected allowed for the project to load again.

Answer (score 35):

You will also get 'root element is missing' when the BOM strikes :). BOM = byte order mark. This is an extra character that gets added to the start of a file when it is saved with the wrong encoding.
This can happen sometimes in Visual Studio when working with XML files. You can either code something to remove it from all your files, or if you know which file it is you can force visual studio to save it with a specific encoding (utf-8 or ascii IIRC).

If you open the file in an editor other than VS (try notepad++), you will see two funny characters before the <? xml declaration.

To fix this in VS, open the file in VS and then depending on the version of VS

- File > Advanced Save Options > choose an appropriate encoding
- File > Save As > keep the filename, click the drop-down arrow on the right side of the save button to select an encoding

Answer (score 17):

In my case.I was getting *missing element error* pointing to `NuGet.Config` file.
At that time it was looking some thing like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
  <repositoryPath>Packages</repositoryPath>
</settings>
```

then I just added `configuration` tag that actually wraps entire xml. Now working fine for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <settings>
     <repositoryPath>Packages</repositoryPath>
  </settings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Awesome!!! Seems it depends on the version of visual studio. In VS 2012, the first step would work but in VS 2015, I don't think so.

Answer (score 11):

This error is caused by corrupted proj file.

Visual Studio always has backup project file at specific folder.

Please browse to:

```
C:\Users\<Your user>\Documents\Visual Studio <Vs version>\Backup Files\<your project>
```

You should see 2 files like this:

```
Original-May-18-2018-1209PM.<your project>.csproj
Recovered-May-18-2018-1209PM.<your project>.csproj
```

You only need copy file:

```
Original-May-18-2018-1209PM.<your project>.csproj
```

And re-name as

```
<your project>.csproj
```

and override at root project folder.

Problem is solved!

Comment: This worked for me using Visual Studio 2015. There were additional original and recovered files in the backup files folder. I deleted all but the most recent and then followed the steps above. I told VS to reload the project and the project loaded.

Answer (score 10):

My project did not load and gave me a `Root Element Missing`error. I just deleted `****.csproj.user` file  and reloaded it again. The problem was solved this way

Answer (score 7):

In my case, when I opened the `.csproj` file, it was empty so I went to my previous commit in git and copied the contents of that file and pasted it my current `.csproj` file. After which I deleted the `.csproj.user` file, reloaded my project, and everything started working again.

Answer (score 5):

You can also search for the file.  Navigate to your project directory with PowerShell and run Get-FileMissingRoot:

```
function Get-FileMissingRoot {

    dir -recurse |
        where {
            ($_ -is [IO.FileInfo]) -and 
            (@(".xml", ".config") -contains $_.extension) 
        } |
        foreach {
            $xml = New-Object Xml.XmlDocument;
            $filename = $_.FullName
            try {
                $xml.Load($filename)
            }
            catch {
                write ("File: " + $filename)
                write ($_.Exception.Message)
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue running VS 2017, on build I was getting the error that the 'root element was missing'. What solved it for me was going to **Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > General > Clear all Nuget Caches**. After doing that I ran the build again and it was fixed.

Comment: I had the same issue in `MSVS 2019` for dotnet core project. Your solution fixed the issue.

Comment: great, worked for me with VS 2019 and .net core 3.1

Answer (score 4):

I got same error. showing error Microsoft.Data.Entity could not loaded root element missing. When i delete that file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 and again open my solution my problem was solved. Everything woks fine

Answer (score 4):

In my case, .csproj was changed to encoded format. I did undo changes to csproj in Git(Team explorer) and reloaded the project file. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the file `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\PreEmptive Solutions\Dotfuscator Professional Edition\4.0\dfusrprf.xml` was full of NULL.

I deleted it; it was recreated on the first launch of Dotfuscator, and after that, normality was restored.

Comment: Fixed by the same .. followed to file that not found deleted him and new file was created automatically .

Answer (score 2):

This error can sometimes occur when you edit some Project Toolchain settings Atmel Studio 6.1.2730 SP2.

In my case I tried to edit Project Properties > Toolchain > Linker > General settings with 'All Configurations' selected in the Configuration. When I checked or unchecked a setting, a dialog with the error popped up. However, I found that I could make the same edits if I made them to only one build configuration at a time; i.e. with only 'Debug' or 'Release' selected instead of 'All Configurations'.

Interestingly, I later was able to edit the same Linker settings even with 'All Configurations' selected. I don't know what changed in my project that made this possible.

Comment: Just encountered the same issue when adding a C #define for "All configurations". Seems that AtmelStudio is not able to to this for all configurations even when Debug/Release containing the same defines.

Answer (score 2):

I had Blue Screen while running Visual Studio 2013,  when I Restart I intended to run again my project, but I had always this headius Error.
anyway

**Deleting The Folders with the Temp info Fix this problem**.
in my case the Project was a Windows Server, and Basically it Creates a Folder  with some Tem info.

the folder was

```
C:\Users\User_NAME\AppData\Local\NAme_OF_THeProject
```

inside Exist a Folder with the Name of the Project+ some Generated GUI
Service.ServerHostLoader_Url_u2jn0xkgjf1th0a3i2v03ft15vj4x52i

this is the Folder I deleted and now I can run again the Project.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I upgraded to VS2017 and wanted to build all projects with MSBuild 4 with my build script (which had been using MSBuild 3.5 when we were using VS2015). That MSBuild upgrade appeared fine for the Windows desktop applications but the ones for Windows CE with compact framework would give me this confusing error. Reverting to MSBuild 3.5 for Windows CE projects fixed the issue for me.

I did have the BOM in .csproj files by the way and removed them for all projects in a solution that would not build but that did not help.

Answer (score 2):

In xamarin form project. I deleted

```
.VS Project folder.
ProjectName.Android.csProj.User
ProjectName.Android.csProj.bak
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I received a message like this:
[See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIVGp.jpg)

I just commented the snipped code below in the project file (.csproj) and the problem was fixed.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case xxxx.pubxml.user was not loaded when tried to publish the application. I deleted the file and restart the Visual studio then created a new profile to publish it, problem is solved and published successfully.

Answer (score 1):

**Hey, I have the same issue on Mac working on a Cocoa C# solution.**
**(But I solved it !)**

It always say that the root element is missing so it cannot load my C# project file.

I have the 2017 Visual Studio Mac Community Edition.
I finally managed to find a solution after several hours (painful!).

My solution is because the frameworks related to the Visual Studio are old or broken.
I found this because I tried to create a new Mac solution by Cocoa and it said "failed to save the solution". Then, I tried to create an Android Solution and it is working fine.
Go to your "Finder" and "Go" -> "Go to a Folder" then go to the "Library/Frameworks". I have deleted mono.framework and frameworks related to Xamarin because I believe these Xamarin frameworks are broken.

Then, uninstalled the Visual Studio and reinstalled it. 
Now everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just renamed the .csproj.user and restart the visual studio and opened the project. It automatically created another .csproj.user file and the solution worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ho i simply solved this issue by going to source control explorer and selected the issue project, right clicked and selected the option Get Specific Version under Advanced menu. And then selected Type as Latest Version and ticked following two check boxes and clicked Get button. Then i refreshed the solution and my project came back to live and problem gone. Please note that This may overwrite your local projects so your current changes may lose. So if you dont have any issues with your local copy then you can try this. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue on a Web API project.  Finally figured out that it was in my "///" method comments.  I have these comments set to auto-generate documentation for the API methods.  Something in my comments made it go crazy.  I deleted all the carriage returns, special characters, etc.  Not really sure which thing it didn't like, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the RDLC files work with resource files (.resx), I had this error because I hadn't created the correspondent resx file for my rdlc report.

My solution was add the file .resx inside the App_LocalResources in this way:

```
\rep
\rep\myreport.rdlc
\rep\App_LocalResources\myreport.rdlc.resx
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a few massive VS2015 Community crashes.

> Delete all the .csproj.user files

which were full of null characters, and also these

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\
>
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error because of an **empty `packages.config` file.**
This caused the NUGET package manager to fail and show the error **Root element is missing.**
The resolution was to copy over elements from another non-empty file and then change it according to the needs.

**Example (packages.config):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net451"/>
 <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.4" targetFramework="net451"/>
</packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was using vs 2010 with crystal report. Innerexception revealed root element is missing error. Go to directory like C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\dssms\dssms.vshost.exe_Url_uy5is55gioxym5avqidulehrfjbdsn13\1.0.0.0 which is given in the innermessage and make sure user.config is proper XML (mine was blank for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the .user file is exactly what fixed the problem for me. Lightning strike near the office shut my PC down and corrupted my .user file and project wouldn't load. I opened the file in Notepad++ and the "spaces" turned out to be [NULL] characters. Deleted the .user file and the file loaded!

source https://forums.asp.net/t/1491251.aspx?Can+t+load+project+because+root+element+is+missing+

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a Xamarin Forms project. iOS project was unavailable and I couldn't reload the project. I was looking for a solution that doesn't need uninstalling anything.

The answer I got from this blog:
https://dev.to/codeprototype/xamarin-form-application-failed-to-load-android-project-root-element-missing--27o0

So without uninstalling anything, you could *delete the* **.csproj.user** file (or rename it) so Visual Studio will create the file again. Worked for me twice.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem occurred due to closing my PC while visual studio were remain open, so in result csproj.user file saved empty. Thankfully i have already backup, so i just copied all xml from csproj.user and paste in my affected project csproj.user file ,so it worked perfectly.

This file just contain building device info and some more.

Answer (score 0):

No one of these solutions fixed my problem.

In my case, I finished my work and I shut down my computer. The day after I wasn't able to compile my project. I tried some of these solutions and I realized all my projects weren't work.

To Fix it, I reinstall .net core Framework.

**Visual Studio 2017**

Answer (score 0):

In my case ***Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets*** was corrupted. I copied this file from other system and it worked.