# Get the error "Root element is missing" when i try to get the tags in textblock

Tags: c#, xml, windows-runtime

I want to get the tags from the xml file to get it in textblock.

my code is :

```
    private async void btnPlantel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         try
         {
             var doc = XDocument.Parse(txtnome.Text);
             var doc2 = XDocument.Parse(txtshirtnumber.Text);
             StorageFolder storageFolder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
             StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("players2.xml");

             txtnome.Text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
             txtshirtnumber.Text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);

             txtnome.Text = (string)doc.Root.Element("name");
             txtshirtnumber.Text = (string)doc2.Root.Element("shirtnumber");

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             txterror.Text = ex.Message;
         }
}
```

and xml is:

```
   <player>
     <name>Ricardo Ferreira Rodrigues</name>
     <shirtnumber>1</shirtnumber>
   </player>
```

but all i get in the txtbox is the error "Root element is missing". Someone can help me?

Comment: You should give a try to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772486/how-to-fix-root-element-is-missing-when-doing-a-visual-studio-vs-build Hope it Works for you

Answer (score 3):

You try to parse the xml(*XDocument.Parse*) before loading it from file. No need to read the file twice, No need to parse the xml twice.

In fact all your code is scrambled, It should be something like this(untested)

```
 StorageFolder storageFolder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
 StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("players2.xml");

 string xml = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);

 var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

 txtnome.Text = (string)doc.Root.Element("name");
 txtshirtnumber.Text = (string)doc.Root.Element("shirtnumber");
```

**Steps:**

- Read the text file
- Parse the xml using XDocument.Parse
- Fill the textboxes with values from xml document