# Running Default ASP.NET version 4.0 web Application gives - Server Error in '/'Application

Tags: asp.net, .net

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Root element is missing.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File:  D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config    Line:  0

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

Answer (score 0):

[How to fix "Root element is missing." when doing a Visual Studio (VS) Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772486/how-to-fix-root-element-is-missing-when-doing-a-visual-studio-vs-build)

Make sure that your web.config isn't empty. It needs a `<configuration>` element at the root.