# WP 8.1 Application manifest generation failed. Root element is missing

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, manifest

I have problem with creating new Windows Phone 8.1 project (Silverlight). I'm getting error "Application manifest generation failed. Root element is missing."

I can't figure out why this is happening and how to fix it.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A good response, and one that may apply to your situation, may be found in:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772540/2578418

but specifically for your Windows Phone project, have you checked each XML file in your project?   Namely:  AppManifest.xml, WMAppManifest.xml, and Package.appxmanifest (all of which seem to be needed by Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1)

If any one of this is missing a root element it could cause the error you are getting.  Here is an example of a well-formed AppManifest.xml

```
   <Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
      <Deployment.Parts>
      </Deployment.Parts>
    </Deployment>
```