# Can't start a new C++ project on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I just installed Visual Studio community 2015 onto my computer (Win 10) and each time I try to create a C++ project I get this message:

> Unable to read the project file "projectname.vcxproj". C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\neutral\Windows.arm.props : error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing

Comment: Are you creating an arm project? Looks like an install failure. There were a few installation bugs with Visual Studio 2015. Did you fully update it to the latest release?

Comment: It's a common problem and has been asked before
check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772486/how-to-fix-root-element-is-missing-when-doing-a-visual-studio-vs-build)