# How to use @Html.BeginForm() properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I try to create a form with `Html.BeginForm()` helper. But it throws exceptions:

```
XmlException: Root element is missing.
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)

CryptographicException: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(byte[] plaintext)
```

This is standard ASP.Net MVC Application. I changed the controller code, add view-model and view classes. That's all.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Login(UserVM userVM)
        {
            return Json(userVM);
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class UserVM
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }


    }
```

View:

```
@using WebApplication1.ViewModels
@model UserVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Email)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m=>m.Password)
}
```

This is what I get:
[image: Screenshot of exception page]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: When and where do you get that exception?

Comment: @SᴇM when I try open page which should return this view. I record video for example https://youtu.be/yVmz1YwWoV8

Comment: Is your config correct? No need of video, just exception message and when/where it occurs (video is some next level stuff).

Comment: @SᴇM what you mean?

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772486/how-to-fix-root-element-is-missing-when-doing-a-visual-studio-vs-build).

Comment: @SᴇM when i comment ```@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))``` block it works fine

Comment: Well, you need also to remove `@` from the beginning of Html's inside `using` block.

Comment: @SᴇM no, it's the correct syntax

Comment: Given the issue is around key management not being able to read some XML file, I'm guessing this has something to do with `AntiForgeryToken`. Try commenting that out to test?

Comment: @CoryNelson same result

Comment: @mykmykpet , I test your code ,and it worked.Did you try to create a new simple project to test ? [Here](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/EawDazZbcV5MiVCTRJQC1kQBAEvc8A0DmrVoEq71oL6aHg?e=UNzjQg) is my demo , you could check the difference . If you still have the problem , could yo share the sample demo ?