# Azure, MVC Core Web App suddenly throw "XmlException: Root element is missing" + "CryptographicException"

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, xmlexception

I have a web application hosted by an **Azure** App service. It has worked fine for years but suddenly I get an Exception when i try to enter the Account/login action:
-->**"XmlException: Root element is missing" + "CryptographicException: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data."**. 
If i got to Home/About action (which have `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute) that page works fine. 
But if i try to enter a page within the Account controller which have the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute. That also throw the same Exception. So I am guessing the Exception occur in the constructor for the Account controller. See below.

I have not made any updates to the page in months and it has worked fine until now.
If I run the application locally on my PC (connected to the same database on azure) it works fine.
As I understand Azure have recently made updates to their portal. 
My guess is that the cause of the error is related to that.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IEmailSender emailSender,
        ILogger<AccountController> logger,
        ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772486/how-to-fix-root-element-is-missing-when-doing-a-visual-studio-vs-build

Comment: I don't think it's the AccountController. What's the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: @RyanHill-MSFT Maby you are right. The stack is to long to paste here. But if you tro to go to the page [link](https://brflillaangar.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login)
You will see it.

Comment: @FredrikLing in looking at the stack trace, looks like you're using an anti-forgery tag helper on your Login page (either on the markup or the code-behind itself) that's referencing data protection. How did you configure your data protection in Startup.cs? Also, what AspNetCore version are you using? Your issue looks very similar to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4167.

Comment: @RyanHill-MSFT Yes you were on the right track as it seems. I fount the cause of the problem and solved it. See answers below. Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I found the problem myself. After digging in to Debug snapshots available in Azure i got a hint that the directory where the app was trying to get the xml causing the exception was "D:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys". When I analysed the content of that directory I saw that one xml-file was empty. I Deleted that file. And that solved the problem.