# Xamarin.andriod load failed HELP ME

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw59C.png)I have a cross playform app with xamarin and vs2019 today when I wanted to modify some stuff the xamarin.android project was saying that load was failed. I've tried everything from renaming and deleting the driod.csproj.user file and I can't find ANY help online..

Comment: Could you please share more details. Like any load failed error details? Have you tried unloading and reloading the project?

Comment: @Ranjit , yes i have done all those this , tried cleaning the project reloading but i get a root element is missing error

Comment: have a look at the picture above...

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772486/how-to-fix-root-element-is-missing-when-doing-a-visual-studio-vs-build