# XmlException and CryptographicException when running blazor web server app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I receive these two exceptions when I run my blazor web server app:

1. XmlException: Root element is missing.
2. CryptographicException: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to
   the inner exception for more information.

I just created the project and run it... I didn't write any piece of code .
Any help is appreciated because I didn't find any solution till now.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: You basically have some corrupt data somewhere. Create another project and see if it happens again?

Comment: What's your Visual Studio's version? I think it may be missing some data, Check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772486/how-to-fix-root-element-is-missing-when-doing-a-visual-studio-vs-build) and try to upload your vs and create a new project to try again.

Comment: @JesseGood I did create more than a project and still have the same issue but with Blazor web assembly model everything is working fine

Comment: @XinranShen Dear I am using vs 2019 I also tried the answer in the issue you are pointing at before asking the question here..

Comment: @someone, Does this  issue only show in Blazor or anyother project in VS?

Comment: @XinranShen only Blazor Web Server other projects works well even Blazor Web Assembly is working good

Comment: @someone,You can create a new blazor project and push it to github, I can test your project in my visual studio, If there is nothing wrong in my pc,I think it can rule out the error of blazor itself

Comment: @XinranShen I just created a new project with the same issue Link : https://github.com/HaNassar/Blazor ... Thanks in advance

Comment: @someone, I have tried your code in my PC, I tested it in `visual studio 2019` and `visual studio 2022` and it all can work well, So there is nothing wrong with the project itself, I think you can repair your visual studio in `Visual Studio Installer` first and try again.

Comment: @XinranShen thanks for your efforts i will check VS to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have found two solutions to fix this issue if someone faced it later.

links to solution:

1. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12830#issuecomment-517907537
2. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12830#issuecomment-606173185